# How to write a script on window that can turn off screen after 10 min in stand by mode or in lock screen mode

Tags: window

I got a plan to write a script file on window that can turn off computer's screen after 10 min in stand by mode or in lock screen mode in order to save the electricity for school.

Now this is just in idea phase, I haven't done any in-depth study since don't know where to start! So I just put a new topic here :D. Hope I could get support from you guys.

If any one ever did a task like this, plz give me an advice about how can I start, which language should be using or which documents, reference to look at!

Thanksss